# How to avoid open-redirect vulnerability and safely redirect on successful login (HINT: ASP.NET MVC 2 default code is vulnerable)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, redirect, security

Normally, when a site requires that you are logged in before you can access a certain page, you are taken to the login screen and after successfully authenticating yourself, you are redirected back to the originally requested page. This is great for usability - but without careful scrutiny, this feature can easily become an [open redirect](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) vulnerability.

Sadly, for an example of this vulnerability, look no further than the default LogOn action provided by ASP.NET MVC 2:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password)) {
            FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) {
                return Redirect(returnUrl); // open redirect vulnerability HERE
            } else {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

        } else {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "User name or password incorrect...");
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

If a user is successfully authenticated, they are redirected to "returnUrl" (if it was provided via the login form submission).

Here is a simple example attack (one of many, actually) that exploits this vulnerability:

1. Attacker, pretending to be victim's bank, sends an email to victim containing a link, like this: `http://www.mybank.com/logon?returnUrl=http://www.badsite.com`
2. Having been taught to verify the ENTIRE domain name (e.g., google.com = GOOD, google.com.as31x.example.com = BAD), the victim knows the link is OK - there isn't any tricky sub-domain phishing going on.
3. The victim clicks the link, sees their *actual* familiar banking website and is asked to logon
4. Victim logs on and is subsequently redirected to `http://www.badsite.com` which is made to look exactly like victim's bank's website, so victim doesn't know he is now on a different site.
5. `http://www.badsite.com` says something like "We need to update our records - please type in some extremely personal information below: [ssn], [address], [phone number], etc."
6. Victim, still thinking he is on his banking website, falls for the ploy and provides attacker with the information

Any ideas on how to maintain this redirect-on-successful-login functionality yet avoid the open-redirect vulnerability?

I'm leaning toward the option of splitting the "returnUrl" parameter into controller/action parts and use "RedirectToRouteResult" instead of simply "Redirect". Does this approach open any new vulnerabilities?

***Update***

By limiting myself to controller/action routes, I can't redirect to custom routes (e.g. `/backend/calendar/2010/05/21`). I know that by passing more parameters to the LogOn action, I *could* get it to work, but I feel like I'll always be revisiting this method -- keeping it up to date with our routing scheme. So, instead of splitting the returnUrl into its controller/action parts, I am keeping returnUrl as-is and parsing it to make sure it contains only a relative path (e.g., `/users/1`) and not an absolute path (e.g., `http://www.badsite.com/users/1`). Here is the code I'm using:

```
private static bool CheckRedirect(string url) {
    try {
        new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
    }
    catch (UriFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

*Side note: I know this open-redirect may not seem to be a big deal compared to the likes of XSS and CSRF, but us developers are the only thing protecting our customers from the bad guys - anything we can do to make the bad guys' job harder is a win in my book.*

Thanks, Brad

Comment: If memory serves, returnUrl must match one of your routes, or the thing will YSOD. But I could be wrong. Have you tested this to prove it is a vulnerability?

Comment: I just tested it. It's true. Another related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782710/what-is-it-about-the-default-asp-net-mvc-accountcontroller-code-that-some-hate)

Comment: If it will make you feel better, I'm pretty sure that the `Redirect` does *not* do a POST, but a GET only.  But I don't suppose that helps you if the sensitive information is passed in the redirect URL as parameters also.

Comment: Are there any further gotcha's with the updated method? It stopped my simple examples (eg redirecting to google, but anyone wanna chime in on the ability to sneak redirects through that?)

Answer (score 9):

Jon Galloway wrote up an [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks) with a solution for MVC 2 (and 1).

Here's the snippet that should help with your issue:

**SECURED** (original article updated 2014)

```
private bool IsLocalUrl(string url)
{
  return System.Web.WebPages.RequestExtensions.IsUrlLocalToHost(
      RequestContext.HttpContext.Request, url);
}
```

Comment: This is of course similar to your update, without the expense of catching an exception.

Comment: This method is vulnerable to links to other protocols like ftp. Please do not use this code. The article mentioned links to the Microsoft provided IsLocalUrl which does not have these issues.

Comment: thanks @BoyBaukema - updated per the articles current direction

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a vulnerability. Before redirecting you need to inspect the `returnUrl` string parameter by passing it to a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) object and make sure that the target domain is the same as the requesting domain. You should also take into account the case when `returnUrl` is a relative address like `/admin`. No problem in this case as the redirect will be to the same application.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - seems to be working fine so far! Please see my update to the original question for details on how I'm parsing the returnUrl.

Answer (score 1):

You could always keep a record of the previous page with TempData when the user is not authenticated and use that to redirect to the previous page instead of a url parameter.

Comment: I don't think this would work - TempData only persists through 1 redirect. In this instance, a person tries to hit a secured URL which causes their browser to redirect to the login. After typing in the username/password, they login and are redirected back to the originally requested page. This is two redirects, so TempData can't work. A better idea might be to attach the redirect URL to the Session?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use one of the variants of Redirect that uses controller and action parameters or a route name, you should be alright, provided you have adequate security controls on your controller methods.

The concept being, whatever you use for your redirect must go through the routing engine and be validated by matching a route.

But I suspect that the real vulnerability is Cross-Site Scripting.  Unless your malicious user can inject some Javascript into the page, they have no way of manipulating the return Url, or any of its parameters (since you otherwise control all of the server and browser code).

Comment: Please see my update - I chose to parse the returnUrl, ensuring that it isn't an absolute URL.