# How to fix Open Redirect URL in Asp.net version 2.0

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I am using  response.redirect in my c# code, but it is showing a **open redirect** vulnerability.

The code is below:

```
Response.Redirect("abcd.aspx?catId=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dropdown.SelectedValue) + "");
```

What code I can use to fix the open redirect vulnerability.

Comment: Hello @Brad Larson, As you can see the code given by me , in response.redirect we are using a virtual path. So, i am bit confused by the suggestion given by you. Can you please give a clear picture **or code**, that helps me in solving this? I have tried the solution given by Darvin given in here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909706/how-to-avoid-open-redirect-vulnerability-and-safely-redirect-on-successful-login/2910534#2910534) But it doesn't works for me. As per my knowledge it is useful for MVC but in my case it is simple ASp.net website with 2.0 version.

Answer (score 1):

As Darin Dimitrov states in [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909706/how-to-avoid-open-redirect-vulnerability-and-safely-redirect-on-successful-login/2910534#2910534):

> Yes this is a vulnerability. Before redirecting you need to inspect
>   the returnUrl string parameter by passing it to a Uri object and make
>   sure that the target domain is the same as the requesting domain. You
>   should also take into account the case when returnUrl is a relative
>   address like /admin . No problem in this case as the redirect will be
>   to the same application.

Comment: Please blockquote any text that is copied from another source, as I have done above. This makes it clear what words are and are not yours.